# how to reset Angular material toggle

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

```
<div id="slider-group" *ngFor="let sliderToggle of sliderToggleGroup">
    <div>
        <mat-slide-toggle  (ngModelChange)="targetedItemChangeListener($event,sliderToggle)"
           [(ngModel)]="sliderToggle.isChecked">
            {{sliderToggle.name}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to reset all slider items to false when a user clicks on reset Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code on a button click event:

```
angular.forEach(sliderToggleGroup, function (value, key) { 
    value.isChecked = false;
});
```